# "Неспортсмен", "неспортсменка" - правописание

Tags: словообразование

Как правильно пишется слово "неспортсмен"? Можно ли его использовать в женском роде, то есть писать "неспортсменка"?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

> Как правильно пишется слово "неспортсмен"?

Если это именно слово, а не отрицание того, что кто-то спортсмен, то так и пишется, слитно.

Но вообще лучше посмотреть всю фразу и контекст в целом. Выбор орфографии зависит от смысла.

> Можно ли его использовать в женском роде, то есть писать "неспортсменка"?

Можно. По тем же основаниям.

> К 10 годам у спортсменок показатель менялся в сторону увеличения
>   равновесия (94,9%) и уменьшения симпатического тонуса вегетативной
>   нервной системы (5,1%). В то время как у неспортсменок показатель
>   менялся в сторону уменьшения равновесия (87,7%) и увеличения
>   симпатического тонуса вегетативной нервной системы (12,24%).

Здесь абсолютно корректное использование понятия "неспортсменка" - девушка, не занимающаяся спортом. Замечаний нет.

Одно полезное наблюдение. Если перед сомнительным сочетанием "не"+"существительное" стоит предлог, то написание слитное. В ином случае предлог попадает между "не" и существительным - *"не у спортсменок"*. 
Вопрос в общем случае только в правомерности использования самого сочетания, но если признать его нормативным, то орфография сомнений не вызывает. "Неспортсменка" представляется вполне законным, это не отрицание спортивности, это самостоятельное качество, здесь - принадлежность к контрольной группе.

Comment: вот предложение:К 10 годам у спортсменок показатель менялся в сторону увеличения равновесия (94,9%) и уменьшения симпатического тонуса вегетативной нервной системы (5,1%). В то время как у неспортсменок показатель менялся в сторону уменьшения равновесия (87,7%) и увеличения симпатического тонуса вегетативной нервной системы (12,24%).

Comment: то есть сравниваются обычные школьницы,не занимающиеся спортом со спортсменками

Comment: да, понял. ответил.

Comment: "У юных спортсменов игровых видов спорта, особенно при занятиях баскетболом, происходит более раннее доминирование тонуса парасимпатической нервной системы, чем у их сверстников-неспортсменов."

                               Это выражение я нашла в автореферате диссертации....Видимо слово неспортсмен, как "указание" на отсутствие у таких людей занятий спортом,можно использовать....и видимо,неспортсменка тоже)))

Comment: Дело не в спортсмене конкретно и уж тем более  не в женском роде. Подобные слова **всегда** или почти всегда можно использовать, если только они **соответствуют представлению о новом понятии**, образуемом с помощью этой частицы. Есть несколько случаев, когда это точно не новое понятие, а явное отрицание, но актуален, пожалуй только один, явное противопоставление: ***Не** спортсмен, **а** тренер.*  - Здесь слитное написание невозможно в принципе. А вот в случае "***не** спортсмен, **но** тренер*" - уже есть варианты. Так что не думайте много над самим словом, смотрите контекст.